# Where can the parity blockchain files be found?

Tags: blockchain, parity, mac-osx, ropsten

On my Mac I am looking for the Parity blockchain file for the `ropsten` chain.
I checked the following locations:

- `~/.parity` and
- `~/.local` but both directories don't exist.
- `~/.ethash` contains 1gb sized files but neither I am certain if these files contain the blockchain nor which one represents the `ropsten` chain.

Comment: That's the paths for Linux :)

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac the blockchain data is stored in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db` in a folder called `906a34e69aec8c0d`

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 7 machine, it's in C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Parity\Ethereum\chains